# How to use doMC under Windows or alternative parallel processing implementation for glmnet?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

I am on Win7 OS with R 3.3.1 in Rstudio. Intention is to use `glmnet` with parallel processing. From the `?glmnet` help:

> `parallel`: If `TRUE`, use parallel foreach to fit each fold. Must
>   register parallel before hand, such as `doMC` or others. See the
>   example below.

From the referenced example:

```
# Parallel
require(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=4)
```

`install.packages('doMC')` returns package is not available. Manually checking [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html) gives downloadable UNIX code but Windows binaries are not available.

Can I still use `doMC` like code under my Win7 OS or what is a useful alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As written in the vignette to `doMC`

> The doMC package acts as an interface between foreach and the
> multicore functionality of the parallel package, originally written by
> Simon Urbanek and incorporated into parallel for R2.14.0. The
> multicore functionality currently only works with operating systems
> that support the fork system call (which means that Windows isn't
> supported)

You can try to use the `snow` package and a `SOCK` cluster instead. (Thx @HongOoi for the hint that loading `doSNOW` is not really required.)

```
library(doParallel)

#the following line will create a local 4-node snow cluster
workers = makeCluster(4, type="SOCK")
registerDoParallel(workers)

foreach(i=1:4) %dopar% Sys.getpid()
```

Comment: You don't really need doSNOW for a Snow cluster; the parallel package (which comes with R) and doParallel will also handle Snow clusters.

Comment: @HongOoi doSNOW has certain advantages over doParallel because of restrictions in the parallel package. For example, doSNOW supports progress bars and calling the combine function on-the-fly.

Comment: One comment, I need to load `library(snow)`. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: For me, I had to make sure snow is installed, but no need to explicitly load it using `load(snow)`