# gbm + plyr + doMC cannot open the connection in R

Tags: r, foreach, plyr, gbm, domc

I have a data set about home prices in the US. The data span 50 different states. I want to build a GBM per state in a parallel fashion. I also want to take advantage of the `cv.folds` argument in the `gbm` package in R. I want to do a 3-fold CV to get the best `n.trees` value.

My Code:

```
library(gbm)
library(plyr)
library(doMC)
doMC::registerDoMC(cores = detectCores())

gbms = dlply(.data = df, .variables = "State", .fun = function(df_temp) {
    gbm(log(Price) ~ ., 
        data = df_temp[, c(features, outcome)],
        distribution = "gaussian",
        n.trees = 5000,
        shrinkage = 0.001,
        interaction.depth = 3,
        n.minobsinnode = 10,
        bag.fraction = 0.5,
        train.fraction = 0.8,
        cv.folds = 3, # if I turn this to 0, the code runs fine
        keep.data = FALSE
        )
    }, .parallel = TRUE
  )
```

The above code returns the following error:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "cannot open the connection"
```

However, if I change `cv.folds = 3` to `cv.folds = 0` the code runs fine and I get my 50 GBMs but they are not optimized against `n.trees`.

Note that if I set `.parallel = FALSE` then the code works fine but it takes a very very long time since it would run on a single core. I also got the same exact error when I tried building the models with `foreach`.

How can I fix this? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're on Windows, note that doMC requires Linux. Use doParallel instead.

Comment: Maybe this [Q&A on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426115/how-to-use-domc-under-windows-or-alternative-parallel-processing-implementation) is of interest to you.

Comment: I'm running my script on an EC2 instance with Amazon Linux AMI so its not a Windows problem.